# How to multithread in Network Service?

Tags: android, multithreading, networking

Now I am working on a ListView which retrieves data from a server, and each item contains images that needs to be renderred to an ImageView. According to my knowledge of Android, the network service should be bind/unbind for each network access, and the image to be renderred should be retained from an InputStream which comes from the network service.

Briefly, the scenario is like the android market app, which renders each app with their own logos asynchronically. How does the Market App make it?

I am now totally lost how to structure the code...

Would anybody kindly help to show some snippet that works?

Comment: Lazy, Lazy ... google + Lazy image loader android

Comment: Enormous thanks, Selvin, I have adapted the LazyList into my project and it works great.

Answer (score 0):

Look into Asynchtask of android api.

Hope this help you